# can't open the dropdown button group by btn-group open

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

.open is not work in bootstrap 4.3 after the btn-group class to open the dropdown  ....

i want to use the directive to load the dropdown without javascript of the bootstrap..

this is the directive :

```
    @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
    @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }
```

and this is the html code :

```
 <div class="btn-group" >            
            <button 
            type= "button" 
            class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" >
            Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Add to shopping-list</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">edit recipe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">delete recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where do you need the .open class? Is it on the btn-group div or the ul?

Comment: `is not work` Could you add what doesn't work?

Comment: in the btn-group div

Answer (score 1):

data-toggle="dropdown" is missing in your button control. once you add, it should work.

Replace the below line of code for the button in the question.

```
<button type= "button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
```

Comment: This answer is not very clear, please could you add to this and include what the line should look like.

Comment: added the required change. please have a look

Answer (score 1):

I solved this be adding a query selector and accessing the children and setting the class name via the Renderer. In bootstrap 4, the `open` class was replaced by the `show`. Therefore use show instead. Attach the class on the `ul`

As shown Below:

`Dropdown.directive.ts`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appDropdown]"
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  @Input ("appDropdown") index : number;

  constructor(private theElementRef: ElementRef, private theRenderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener("click") toggleDrawer() {
    let elements = this.theElementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.show');

    if (elements.length > 0) {
      this.theRenderer.removeClass(this.theElementRef.nativeElement.children[this.index], "show");
    } else {
      this.theRenderer.addClass(this.theElementRef.nativeElement.children[this.index], "show");
    }
  }

}
```

`template.html`

```
<div [appDropdown]="1" class="btn-group">
<button style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button">Manage Recipe <span
class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add To Shopping List</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remove Recipe</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method in Directive.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from 
                                                                     '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appDropdown]'
})

export class DropdownDirective {

constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
@HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
@HostListener('click') toggleOpen(): void {
this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
let part = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
 if (this.isOpen) {
   this.renderer.addClass(part, 'show');
  }else {
    this.renderer.removeClass(part, 'show');
  }
 }
}
```

Above code snippet will work in bootstrap 4

```
 <div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
    >
    Manage Recipe
  </button>
  <ul  class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">To Shopping List</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of the additional HostBinding Syntax, and you shouldn't listen for a click anywhere, only on the specific element you want to cause an effect.

**TS FILE :**

```
isOpen = false;
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="btn-group" [ngClass]="{'open' : isOpen}" (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Add to shopping-list</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">edit recipe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">delete recipe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: in the course that i watch in the web ... when he write open after btn-group .. the group is opened , this is  before that he write the code of the directive ... but when I write the open word its not do anything . is this because changing of bootstrap version or what ?

Comment: I learn directives now and I want to try the example that I watched

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by replacing the open by 'show' .

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu show">
```

Answer (score 0):

At `<Component>.ts` File, add a property:

```
isOpen = false;
```

Then at corresponding HTML file add below :

```html
<div class="btn-group" >
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
      Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{'show' : isOpen}" >
      <li><a href="#">Add to shopping-list</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">edit recipe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">delete recipe</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem so I solved it by switching the version of bootstrap. I am guessing that you are using the latest version. Just downgrading it to 3.3.7.

In bootstrap 4 there is no class .open but in bootstrap 3 it is.